# The efficient way to implement a vertically translating widget on user drag

Tags: flutter

I want to translate a widget vertically as the user drags. I tried implementing it using two options:

1. AnimationController
2. Value notifier.

So when I use the animation controller the scroll is not very smooth and the widget is being scroll after a delay even when the duration of the animation is 1 milliseconds.

When I implement it using value notifier it is much better but still not as smooth as the ListView scroll. Is there a better way to scroll\translate a widget on user drag?

Comment: Please include your code, as there's a good chance it isn't just the way you're doing the animation but also how you build your widget etc that could be the problem. Also, look into Draggable as it might do what you want.

Comment: I found a better way of doing this. Flutter has a widget for this. I posted my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a better solution for this. Although it can be achieved using Gesture detector but that is not as smooth. Flutter has another wonderful widget for this and that is **DraggableScrollableSheet**.

If you want container for a Scrollable list that responds to drag gestures by resizing the scrollable until a limit is reached, and then scrolling this is the widget you should be using.

```
 DraggableScrollableSheet(
              initialChildSize: .70,
              minChildSize: .70,
              builder: (BuildContext context, ScrollController scrollcontroller){

                scrollcontroller.addListener((){

                });
            return  Container(

                child: ListView.builder(
                    controller: scrollcontroller,
                    itemCount: widget.songs.length,
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                      return buildSongRow(widget.songs[index]);
                    })
            );
          })
```

The above list will be place at the 70 percent of the height of the screen initially. When you scroll up it drags the list up to the top and then the list scrolls as a normal listview. When you reach the top while scrolling, the list drags down to the initial position(70 percent of height).